# Help Creating a Function that calls sql storedprocedure

Tags: sql, vb.net, ado.net

I tried to search forum topics to find a tutorial that will guide me on how to achieve this however seem like most of the tutorials i were finding were confusing me more.With that being said here is what i have,

Here is what I am trying to do 
http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/displaying-data-with-the-objectdatasource-vb

that tutorial is exactly what I am trying to achieve however I do not understand what the supplierstableadpater, northwindtableadapters are. I can only assume that I am not doing exactly the same thing as that tutorial.

What I have is a simple sql storedprocedure that selects all employeedetails.And also another sql stored procedure that selects just a few columns from the employees table. On my frist page I am going to list all the employee names in a gridview and when they click the employee name it should take them to another page and show that employee's details. Seems like you have to use an object datasource to achieve this but is there an easier way to achieve creating a class that calls the 2 stored procedures that I have that i would be able to then link them with an objectdatsource?

I dont expect you to write code for me as I want to learn how to do this myself just hoping someone had some info on where I could go to read up on how to get this done.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the previous articles:

http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/creating-a-data-access-layer-vb
and
http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/creating-a-business-logic-layer-vb

They will provide the background you need.

Comment: Thanks I got this to work finally after hours of trial and error wish i could say i understand half of what i did but guess you have to start some where.

Comment: I do have another question for you they really need to make the enter button on this site go one line down instead of adding the comment haha However my question is what is the approach to retrieving the record using individual textboxes instead of the gridview or formview. Do you happen to know a tutorial on how to achieve that Thanks again for you help